# When I use sio. loadmat with the scipy.io, I get the output undefined file, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, scipy

When I use sio. loadmat with the scipy.io, I get the output undefined file, how can I fix this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA9GF.png)

Comment: Please [post code as text instead of screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3005167).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat) tell you that it expects a string which is interpreted as filepath.
(Alternatively you can pass an file-object which means you need to open some file before and pass this open file)

You are giving some variable/object (probably undefined).

```
a = function(foo)   # argument is an object = foo
a = function('foo') # argument is a string
```

So if your file is named `NFimage_Sub_1_Ses_1.mat`, call it like this:

```
mat_content = sio.loadmat('NFimage_Sub_1_Ses_1.mat')
```

Comment: I have tried that and I get the output there is no such file or directory

Comment: The above is correct. Your error means, that it's not within the folder your script is run. Just add the full system path or a relative one. This is basic python-stuff.

Comment: sorry I am quite new to python , I have set my path to the folder that contains my file, yet I still get this msg

Comment: There is no possible help here as we don't know or control your system. Follow python tutorials to learn about opening files. You are not opening files here (you just pass the path), but the rules you learn from this will help.